# How to backup a s3 bucket to the glacier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I'm having some difficulty setting up my S3 to make an automatic backup to Glacier. That is, I want a copy of my s3 on the glacier every day. How to do this?

Comment: Big picture, what is your actual aim? Point in time snapshots of S3? That would be better done with S3 bucket versioning. You can restore to a point in time quite easily, including recovering files marked deleted. Regarding your question, I don't think AWS offers this functionality directly. You may have to use incremental backup software on an EC2 instance, but maybe someone has a service that will do it for you.

Comment: My goal is to generate a backup of my S3 in case we accidentally delete files.

Comment: It might be a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325943/can-amazon-glacier-mirror-an-amazon-s3-bucket

Answer (score 5):

You can figure out how AWS's API works or just let Veeam do all the job with an additional ransomware protect. https://www.veeam.com/blog/leverage-vtl-on-amazon-aws-object-storage-s3-glacier.html

Answer (score 3):

Since your goal is to be able to recover deleted files you simply need to turn on [S3 versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html). You can recovered files marked as deleted from the console or command line.

If you want to restore / download your bucket as at a point in time use the [S3 Point in Time Restore Tool](https://github.com/madisoft/s3-pit-restore).

AWS has a lot of features. Doing the associate certification is a good way to get a reasonably overview of them. It's important to understand your platform.